# Set up Split-horizon DNS at home

Tags: dns, router, home-networking

I have some services set up on my computers at home. Currently I use a little script to determine if I'm at home, and if so use a LAN IP, and if not use my router's WAN IP to connect to these services.

I would like to simply use DNS for this instead.

This is my router:
http://netgear.com.au/home/products/wirelessrouters/work-and-play/DGN2200.aspx

I have considered installing this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/modfs/
but it appears to be based on the original version of the firmware, which I had to update in order to get VPN working.

Should I:

1. Edit hosts file entries on all my computers
2. Try and get my router to do some DNS (maybe with telnet?)
3. install BIND on one of my machines and configure my router to point to this machine for DNS at home (tried this but couldn't find where to configure this)
4. ditch my router and install some kind of router software on one of my machines, and then use that for DNS
5. Some other option I haven't considered

Basically I want the following:

Outside the network (already works):

- machine1.domain.com -> {WAN IP}
- machine2.domain.com -> {WAN IP}

Inside the network:

- machine1.domain.com -> 192.168.0.2
- machine2.domain.com -> 192.168.0.6

Comment: Tell your ISP that you want IPv6, yesterday.

Comment: Actually... looks like my ISP does support it. My router doesn't though. But because of government my ISP is going to change soon, and I don't know the new ISP, so not sure what to do about that. But yeah I actually completely forgot about IPv6 thanks

Comment: You can upgrade the router. Though I am aware that Internet in your country is generally bad...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the latest firmware - https://community.plus.net/forum/index.php?topic=97553.0

Maybe I'll consider using my linux box as a router!

Comment: @MichaelHampton how does IPv6 help the situation? I'm new to networking and not that familiar with the benefits of IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted so far it sounds like you already have your port forwarding configured so you can access your services from either side of your network (inside/outside). If not you'll want to get this set up first.

You've got a few interesting options you can toy with. Some a little more hacked together than others. This sounds like a fun project so let's dive in:

Plan A: My first thought is to do something relatively easy that works with your script for detection. You can have two host files that you switch between. Share both on dropbox across all of your machines and have the script copy the desired version at a given time to your computer to overwrite the existing hosts file. This keeps things dynamic in a way that lets you use the same names for either side of your network but points to different IPs depending on what side you're on.

Plan A2: If you have a domain or dedicated server somewhere you can make use of a script that just writes/reads to an ftp directory with credentials you specify if you don't want to use something like dropbox.

Plan B: If you have an existing domain you can have one of your servers upload your router's external IP at regular intervals. That way you have something with a dedicated address you can get to find out what your external home IP is at all times. From there you can script something that points to that dynamic ip as a variable and uses the ports you mapped for the port forwarding.

Plan C: VPN + internal DNS. Anytime you're outside you just VPN in. Anytime you're inside - you're already pointing to that DNS hopefully. My personal opinion - Windows DNS is a bit easier to use than something like BIND. It's a bit more graphical and point and click. BIND is entirely text based and can be a little intimidating for those unfamiliar. However, you'd need a dedicated Windows Server (this can be virtualized, of course) which usually comes at price - though if you have a *.edu email address you can make use of DreamSpark to get yourself a copy of Windows Server to play around with for free. Alternatively you could do the same with a copy of CentOS and BIND (there are plenty of guides for "Setting up CentOS as DNS server" out there).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've updated my question to show what I really want. I am already implementing Plan B :) Why would I need a dedicated machine for DNS? Surely DNS server software is not very resource heavy? especially for just a home network... I am happy to learn how BIND works... But I can't figure out how to tell my router to use another machine for DNS

Comment: The reason for a dedicated machine is just so you can have something on 24/7. DNS is pretty lightweight for home set up. You could actually run BIND off a Raspberry Pi if you wanted a fun project. That'll save you on energy costs and can even pay for itself in 2-3 months compared to a server or desktop running 24/7. 

As for how to tell your router to use another machine for DNS: what you can do which may simplify things is to make your DNS server ALSO a DHCP server then turn off the DHCP feature on your router. You'll want to ensure your DNS is forwarding to an outside DNS (like 8.8.8.8) too.

Comment: hm ok.... yeah I already have a Windows machine and an Ubuntu machine running 24/7 so not concerned about the cost :) Hm that would mean I would have to install DHCP server software as well wouldn't it? I suppose I'm already giving all my home computers static IPs on the network already so maybe I don't have to worry about that...

Comment: Since we're getting a bit off topic from the original question I'll just point to outside references:For Debian-based OSes (like Ubuntu or Raspbian) I use the PDF linked to here (http://elinux.org/Setting_up_your_Raspberry_Pi_as_a_DHCP_Server). You'll get an error message at first install until you configure it. For Windows Server 2008: (http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/How-to-Install-Configure-Windows-Server-2008-DHCP-Server.html) *Don't forget to activate your scope or you'll feel pretty silly!

Comment: Actually this is what my question is actually about, perhaps I'll change the title of my question

Comment: If you have any other questions feel free to ask. This should get you on your way. :)

Comment: yes thanks ive asked this question on my router's forums: http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=90239
honestly ipv6 is probably my best bet right now

Answer (score 1):

OP wants to set up DNS at home, but  description indicates the real goal is to have home machines resolve to a different IP at home than on the home network. The solution proposed comes close to an implementation of split DNS, which has come to be somewhat frowned upon in some quarters.

I would urge OP to put the internal IPs in the hosts file of the local machines. Presuming the machines are configured to use the default resolution order of files followed by DNS, the IP on the hosts file will preclude anything in DNS.

Comment: Yes taht's exactly what I want! why is that frowned upon? Surely that's a nicer solution than managing hosts files

Answer (score 0):

if you've got static public ip from your ISP, then simply use free dns server (http://my.dot.tk/ etc).
but if you've got dynamic public ip from your ISP, then use dynamic dns manager (http://www.noip.com/ etc).

Comment: This does not solve my problem - i want the ip address reported when i'm at home to be my LAN IP, as opposed to when i am away from home. so (i think) i need to host DNS at my house.

Comment: see if your router have built in DNS server so you don't need to install dns server. i assume you have static public ip, why don't give a try to http://my.dot.tk ?? you can access your server domain name either from LAN / WAN

Comment: I actually have a dynamic IP and implement my own dynamic DNS. I've been trying to see if my router has a built in DNS server with no success so far. I don't see how an internet service could provide my LAN with DNS services.